# RecyclerView changes multiple rows although only one row was targeted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I got a RecyclerView and want to change the appearance of any clicked row. For that I have a callbackFunction in my Activity which I pass to the Adapter, which then is called inside the Adapter, as soon as I click on any row in the RecyclerView.

The clicked row is then changed, but it happens, that not only the clicked rows are changed but also other rows, that weren't clicked and were never clicked before. I checked the ArrayList that contains the data, but everything is fine there. Only the clicked elements contain the trigger to change the appearance of the row.

What is causing the other rows to change, although they have not been clicked?

**Interface inside activity for callback**

```
public interface onHeaderClickListener{

    void onHeaderClicked(int index);

}
```

**Inside RecyclerView Adapter**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    if (holder instanceof ViewHolderHeader){

        ((ViewHolderHeader)holder).dateHeaderTextView.setText( Integer.toString(((objClass_offerDateHeader) arrayList.get(position)).getDate()));

        if(((objClass_offerDateHeader) arrayList.get(position)).isSelected()){
            ((ViewHolderHeader)holder).dateHeaderTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b642f4"));
        }

        ((ViewHolderHeader)holder).dateHeaderTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onHeaderClickListener.onHeaderClicked(position);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Adapter initialisation inside activity**

```
customAdapterRecyclerViewAddOffersTo = new customAdapterRecyclerViewAddOffers(offerArrayList,"dragTo", new onHeaderClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onHeaderClicked(int index) {
        if (offerArrayList.get(index) instanceof  objClass_offerDateHeader){

            if(((objClass_offerDateHeader) offerArrayList.get(index)).isSelected()){
                ((objClass_offerDateHeader) offerArrayList.get(index)).setSelected(false);
            }
            else {
                ((objClass_offerDateHeader) offerArrayList.get(index)).setSelected(true);
            }

            customAdapterRecyclerViewAddOffersTo.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an else condition here:

```
if(((objClass_offerDateHeader) arrayList.get(position)).isSelected()){
            ((ViewHolderHeader)holder).dateHeaderTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b642f4"));
        }
```

Viewholders get recycled, so you cannot be sure of the current state when `onBindViewHolder` is called.

Answer (score 2):

In your `onBindViewHolder` method you have to set the background of the unselected cell, keep in mind the the cells are reused and you only set the background of selected cells so when it is reused the background is not returned to the normal color

So in code you will have to add an else condition

```
if(((objClass_offerDateHeader) arrayList.get(position)).isSelected()){
        ((ViewHolderHeader)holder).dateHeaderTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b642f4"));
    } else {
((ViewHolderHeader)holder).dateHeaderTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); // I assume you need it to be white you can change it to any other color
}
```